# making google chrome prompt you when closing window with multiple tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes, when I'm trying to close a tab, I'll accidentally close an entire window of tabs in Google Chrome. Is there a plugin or something that I could install to make it so it pops up with a confirmation dialog before closing an entire window?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of that question. This is about individual windows, that is about the entire browser.

Comment: I'm sure there's an option for this... But I don't have Chrome installed on this machine!

Comment: @RobinGreen actually yes, because Chrome/ium doesn't have prompts... so you need either a extension or reopen the tabs if you closed by mistake.